# How to add a "click" handler inside the "for" loop?

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop

There is such a piece where how

```
$(document).on('click', '#calcA', function() {
    $("#calcASum").addClass("field");
    ($(this).is(":checked")) ? $("#calcAInfo").css("display", "") : $("#calcAInfo").css("display", "none");
});

$(document).on('click', '#calcB', function() {
    $("#calcBSum").addClass("field");
    ($(this).is(":checked")) ? $("#calcBInfo").css("display", "") : $("#calcBInfo").css("display", "none");
});

$(document).on('click', '#calcC', function() {
    $("#calcCSum").addClass("field");
    ($(this).is(":checked")) ? $("#calcCInfo").css("display", "") : $("#calcCInfo").css("display", "none");
});
```

only AB and C changes; 
I wanted to write through for ()

```
var item = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
for(var i=0; i<item.length; i++) {
    $(document).on('click', '#calc'+item[i], function() {
        $("#calc"+item[i]+"Sum").addClass("field");
        ($(this).is(":checked")) ? $("#calc"+item[i]+"Info").css("display", "") : $("#calc"+item[i]+"Info").css("display", "none");
    });
}
```

he adds one more function after the click function. It turns out inside the function already i = 3. There are other solutions to this problem? thanx

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: The easiest solution is to not use IDs with semantic meaning.  Use DOM traversal to find the related Sum/Info fields or pair them with `data-` attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact is that you are referencing an outer scoped variable.

You can have a look at this question: [Functions declared within loops referencing an outer scoped variable may lead to confusing semantics. What is wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027262/functions-declared-within-loops-referencing-an-outer-scoped-variable-may-lead-to)

And in your case you can try this code :

```
var item = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
for(var i=0; i<item.length; i++) {
    const j = i;
    $(document).on('click', '#calc'+item[j], function() {
        $("#calc"+item[j]+"Sum").addClass("field");
        ($(this).is(":checked")) ? $("#calc"+item[j]+"Info").css("display", "") : $("#calc"+item[j]+"Info").css("display", "none");
    });
}
```

Comment: It's not so much that it's an "outer scoped variable" - it's that the click event occurs *after* the for loop has completed, so the value of `i` has already changed by the time you click.  Have a good read of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work