# Unable to figure out the output of simple javascript code

Tags: javascript, closures

```js
function func2() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 2000);
  }
}

func2();
```

Due to `closure`, the `console.log` statement should remember its outer lexical environment, which is first `setTimeout` and then the for loop. Since `i` is not available in the `setTimeout` context, it looks in the execution context of the for loop, and searches for the value of `i` there.

Now, that value, after 2 seconds, should have been 3 for all three executions of `console.log`. But it displays the output as:

```
0
1
2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Functions declared within loops referencing an outer scoped variable may lead to confusing semantics. What is wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027262/functions-declared-within-loops-referencing-an-outer-scoped-variable-may-lead-to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `let` which is `block scoped` so there will be separate `i` for each for loop iteration.

**1)** If you want to output consective `3` so you can declare `i` outside of `for-loop`, then there will be only single `i` with the value `3`.

```js
function func2() {
  let i;
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 2000);
  }
}

func2();
```

**2)** If you want same lexical scope then you can also use `var` here,

> `var` is function scoped, So there will only be one `i`

```js
function func2() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 2000);
  }
}

func2();
```

Comment: So, each console.log will store a different ancestral lexical environment? I thought that lexical environment were delimited by the ancestor function/s which would be the same for each console.log and in that ancestor function, the value of "i" would be 3. What I now understand is that setTimeout would have a different parent lexical environments stored for each call. Or is it that the lexical environment is the same but the scope of "i" in each call is also stored in  the lexical environment

Comment: Yeah right, You can also use `var` here, `var` is `function-scoped`. Answer udpated