# Why does jshint warn of calling functions from a function declared within a loop?

Tags: javascript, jshint

The following code

```
function foo () {}

let data = [];

for (let x of data)
{
  let bar = function ()
  {
    foo ();
  };
}
```

causes this warning in jshint

```
Functions declared within loops referencing an outer scoped variable may lead to confusing semantics. (foo)
```

I am aware that Javascript has unintuitive rules for binding variables to functions created in a loop. For example (if I've got this right) the following code causes each function object to bind to the same `table`

```
for (let table of document.getElementsByTagName ("table"))
{
  table.my_function = function ()
  {
     do_something_with (table);
  };
}
```

I think jshint is treating these two cases as equally suspicious. But they look different to me. Is this warning something to take seriously, or is jshint being overly paranoid?

Comment: Those two cases look pretty similar, other than passing the variable in the second one. It's about the scope involved. I mean, the warning is kind-of self-explanatory. If you disagree, then disable the warning.

Comment: I see why the warning would be valid for the second example, but not for the first.

Comment: Well when the error says "may lead to confusing semantics" that's clearly just an opinion; I doubt that jsHint performs an extensive static analysis to make it's "maybe confusing" determination. Again, if you disagree (like, if you personally are not confused) then disable the check.

Comment: I don't want to disable the check, it's a useful check, but it seems wrong for the first case. If it's not wrong, I want to know why it's not wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The function has no references to `x`, so there's no need to create a new function each time through the loop. Declare the function once and assign it to each array element.

```
for (let x of data)
{
  x.bar = foo;
}
```

The second code doesn't bind to the same `table` each time. `let` creates a new scope of `table` for each iteration of the loop. If you had used `var table` instead of `let table`, they would have shared scope and they would all use the last value of `table` (see [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example))

Comment: The foo example is constructed to trigger the error. I'm not actually trying to do anything with x.

Comment: And that's why you get the warning -- you're creating a new closure each time even though there's nothing to close over.

Comment: This is a minimalised version of a larger piece of code which yields the same warning. In the larger version, there is something to close over. But it doesn't need something to close over because that's not the issue. The warning is about `foo`, not `x`. I removed references to `x` from the loop to prove this point. The error is about referencing `foo` from the closure. Why is this "confusing semantics"?

Comment: But `foo()` isn't defined in the loop, so I don't think it's warning about that. It's warning about the anonymous function that calls `foo()`, which is assigned to `bar`.

Comment: I have a feeling that this is like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027262/functions-declared-within-loops-referencing-an-outer-scoped-variable-may-lead-to and maybe jshint isn't distinguishing `let` variables from `var` variables (the latter do indeed have problems).